# How to uncommit in Documentation

Tags: discussion, support, documentation

Is it possible to uncommit to an item in `Documentation`?

For example `http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/web-services/commit` allows you to commit to the topic. But what if you clicked wrong or wish to retreat?